Environment variable is not accessible from integrated terminal
With windows 11, i added the environment variable NODE_OPTIONS in my user profile:

This variable is not accessible from the integrated terminal in VS Code, configured to launch Powershell 7:

However the variable is accesible form a PowerShell terminal:

And this works with another environment variable :

I restarted terminal, vscode and computer without success.
The behaviour is the same with a CMD terminal
